# Qt4 Differences between close and destroy?

Tags: qt, pyqt, destroy, qdialog

When i type the command destroy() for a dialog (I haven't tried another types of windows) Qt retuns this message:

```
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 3 (X_ShmPutImage)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 3 (X_ShmPutImage)
  Resource id:  0x0
```

But if i type 'close()' it works correct.

So what's the differences between close() and destroy()? Or is there any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `destroy()` if you don't have a good reason. It is supposed to be part of the destruction, e.g. it is called internally for clean-up. The error messages indicate that during destroy, X window resources are free'd that are still referenced. So they are free'd prematurely.

The method `close()` on the other hand is the proper way to signal that a window/dialog should be closed. It is doing the same as if the user would request a window to close (e.g. clicking on the close button on the window frame title).

Comment: In other words: there's a very good reason for `destroy` to be a protected method. I'm sure it can be of use *somewhere*, but in 10 years of Qt programming I've never had a single reason to use it. Heck, I've long since forgotten it even was there.